# Screen freezes when playing 3D games

Tags: windows, display, crash

Since this morning, my computer started freezing when I play a 3D game, like World of Warcraft. The screen and sometimes the video card stops sending signal to the monitor. I've repaired the game and reinstalled all the drivers, but no luck. I've also downloaded FurMark to stress test the card. After a few seconds from the start of the test, the same stuff happens: screen freezes or no output signal. I have to hard reset the PC to get it back to work. Now, Device Manager says Windows interrupted the device because it has found a problem with it. FurMark says Windows Basic Display Driver is loaded. I've opened the computer, removed the card, cleaned it up, reinstalled, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me with that?

My computer specs and DxDiag output can be found here: https://pastebin.com/zwEAe4Mi. My video card is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 760.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Windows Basic Display Driver" - This means your system is not using the Nvidia display driver.  It also explains the problems you experience with software that require more than a basic display driver to function.

Comment: The basic display driver started being used after the crashes.

Comment: You will have to provide more specific information.  There is no evidence of your card in your report